# Yersinia raw packet

Tags: linux, cisco, dhcp

I'm using `Yersinia` to pentest my network. There are two options *send raw packet* and *creating DHCP rogue server* I don't understand fully.
Can someone explain the meaning of these options?

Comment: Have you tried to Google it :)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_DHCP

Comment: @Vilican yes i did. i never ask something without googling it first. 
I did not find anything about raw socket .

Comment: Antonio - I think the question would get more attention if you added the links you used for research and clarified your problem better as you did in your comment. Also, spelling "rogue" correctly will help.

Answer (score 1):

A DHCP Rogue Server is a DHCP server that is running to deliver faked DHCP Configurations to new clients. In most cases the intention is to deliver either a fake router or a fake DNS-Server or both to perform a MITM attack. Running a DHCP rogue server isn't as easy as it sounds because you have to be faster than the original DHCP server. This will not work when:

- You are performing the attack over WLAN because of the relatively high latency which is fundamental in this attack
- The DHCP-Server is running on the router both you and the victim are connected to because then the router will always be the first to answer the request

And in all other cases you have a chance as long port security is switched off.

Sending RAW DHCP Packets is functionality that can be used to discover the real DHCP server. Yersinia sends a DHCP-Request with a fake MAC and a minimum set of headers. Although it fakes the MAC-Address you will receive the answer. This is because DHCP does address on layer 2 only and by sending a faked request from your port the answer is also sent to your port.

Comment: But if i make mitm i'm the router for the victim , so the dhcp rouge supposed to work no ??

Comment: If you already are the man in the middle you don't need a roughe dhcp server anymore